# Typescript function that asserts sibling is truthy or throws error

Tags: typescript

Code:

```js
// DatabaseUser implementation not too important 
// included for Minimum Reproducible Example
type DatabaseUser = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}

export type GraphQLContext<User extends DatabaseUser | null> = {
  user: User;
  signedIn: User extends DatabaseUser ? true : false;

  // problematic line
  authenticationRequired: () => asserts User is DatabaseUser;
};
```

The logic for `authenticationRequired` will look something like this:

```js
function authenticationRequired(){
  if(!user){
    throw Error("Auth");
  }
}
```

The goal is so that I can in later contexts use call the `authenticationRequired()`

```js
authenticationRequired();


// ts knows user is guaranteed to be truthy at this line
console.log(user.name);
```

I tried making it into a generic like shown at the top but I'm getting the error

> TS1225: Cannot find parameter  `User`

Not completely sure if this is possible but hoping it is.

Comment: The [syntax](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) you're using requires that what is being asserted is part of the function signature. In this case, typescript is looking for a parameter called `User` in the function signature, but fails to find one. This is what causes the error

Comment: ① What's a `DatabaseUser`? Could you [edit] the code here to be a [mre] that we can just copy into our own IDEs to work on it without having to guess about declarations? ② I I just guessed it has some property... if that works, does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/N9Vkom) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz that's actually exactly what I was looking for! Can you put it in a post so that I can mark it as answer

Comment: I will do so when I get a chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return type of an [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) is an `asserts` predicate of the form `asserts arg is Type`, where `arg` is an argument to the function or `this` (making the function an assertion *method*).  So you can't write `asserts User is DatabaseUser` because `User` is neither a function argument or `this`.  You have a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter named `User`, but that's essentially coincidental.

Given that your function doesn't take an argument and given that you're trying to narrow the type of the object on which you call `authenticationRequired()`, you are really looking to use `asserts this is Type`.

All we have to do now is figure out that `Type`. Instead of making your `GraphQLContext` type generic so that it tries to distinguish between a `signedIn` and a not-`signedIn` context, you can just use interface extension to make `SignedInGraphQlContext` a special type of `GraphQLContext`:

```
interface SignedInGraphQLContext extends GraphQLContext {
  user: DatabaseUser;
  signedIn: true;
}
```

And now `authenticationRequired` can return `asserts this is SignedInGraphQLContext`:

```
interface GraphQLContext {
  user: DatabaseUser | null;
  signedIn: boolean;
  authenticationRequired: () => asserts this is SignedInGraphQLContext;
};
```

Let's see it in action:

```
declare const gql: GraphQLContext;
gql.user.name // error, might be undefined
gql.authenticationRequired();
gql.user.name // okay, it works
```

Looks good.

---

Note that assertion functions and methods are somewhat tricky to use; you need an explicit [type annotation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) on `gql` above.  You can't allow the compiler to *infer* the type of the variable without breaking the behavior of the assertion function:

```
const gql2 = gql;
gql2.authenticationRequired(); // error!
```

This doesn't really affect the answer to your question, since you were trying to use an assertion function anyway, but you should be aware of it.  If the above meets your needs, great.  Otherwise you might consider refactoring to use more basic language features like [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions).  But that's out of scope for the question as asked, so I won't digress further.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOAjOBnCBVdAnKBeKAbwCgooBLAEwC4pVhtyA7AcwG5Som4BbCW+o1YcAvsWLNgEbADM4AY2gBxbHDAALAIoAZAMIB7JlIAewIpwCuOWvEQp0WaVAA+XCwBt3HMqnIsmEJQAkky0SPr67hBwTN5QcBbA6hBG5PII5IYAShAAjhbk2IG0ABQAlPgAfPGoOMCoUEnkDc1QAMp+AcFMKmpaeoYmwKIcEkbScortnYEhvRo6BuOmUBCmKZQN8-1LQ+ZkVtI2CMhomDhxvv6zoY3YFhCi4pQQ8u5wRVDyhvRQLLnuWjbRaDNbDYj-dwAOkO2Ch3D4UAA9EjVthsPpsAAaKA8PzqMxIaAWJgvGTMQIQgFQhJJFLANIZbJ5ApFSjlDiQmE4eG8aAoqD6ADWcBAOPIZgA7pihahxN8mL9IQAmfB-AGcgHKmmJZKpdIM5n5QqBDnI1HSDHYACExCAA)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure how to answer this in terms of your exact setup and goals, but I can answer more generally.

I'd recommend creating a function (that may access your context?) that will retrieve the user. This function can throw an error if there is no user, and therefore guarantee the user exists if it returns a value:

```js
function getUser() {
  const user = // ... get the user from your context (or session or db..)

  if (user) {
    return user
  } else {
    throw new Error('user not found')
  }
}
```

Then when you consume this function, if it returns, user will be defined:

```js
const user = getUser()
console.log(user.name) // works fine!
```